# Source and Destination Viewcontroller in Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

How to detect if actual View is coming from source or Destination Viewcontroller in Storyboard?

Comment: Ask it for its `presentingViewController`.

Comment: Can you help me to use it properly? if(presentingViewController== what? ){  }

Comment: unable to understand you. explain it little bit more

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can test `questionedView` that way:

```
    if( [questionedView isDescendantOfView:[storyboardSegue sourceViewController].view] )
    {
      // view is from sourceViewController
    }
```

and

```
    if( [questionedView isDescendantOfView:[storyboardSegue destinationViewController].view] )
    {
      // view is from destinationViewController
    }
```